# Add a Query String to a Wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, url, query-string, addition

I've spent days trying to make sense of WP tutorials, but can't get figure this problem out: I need to add a specific query string to a Wordpress URL in order to activate an element on the page.

For example:

example.com/page
to
example.com/page?give?desig=10000

The query string must appear exactly as above, with the 5 digit number being interchangeable with other numbers.

Also:

I need to be able to add another element:
example.com/page?give?desig=10000?motiv=XXXX-XXXX

The Xs must are an interchangeable alphanumeric sequence separated by a hyphen.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with just linking to' example.com/page?give?desig=10000'? Perhaps you should add an example of your code and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi danbahamri, Sure, I can create internal links and achieve this. But I need anyone who goes to example.com/page to be redirected to example.com/page?give?desig=10000. This will require a 301 redirect which I have not been able to achieve through WP's system. Sorry, I do not have any coding to offer, as I don't know what WP coding would be needed to accomplish this, nor do I know where such coding should be pasted.

Comment: Try this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect